# How to explode first 10 elements of string ignore the rest (comma separated)

Tags: php, arrays

I want to explode the following string upto 10 elements

```
$str = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o";
```

into array $arr.Tried with

```
$arr = explode(",", $str,10);
```

It gives result as

```
Array
(
[0] => a
[1] => b
[2] => c
[3] => d
[4] => e
[5] => f
[6] => g
[7] => h
[8] => i
[9] => j,k,l,m,n,o
)
```

dont want `$arr[9]=j,k,l,m,n,o` should be `$arr[9]=j`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$str = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o";
$arr = explode(",", $str);
$output = array_slice($arr, 0, 10);   // returns a to j
```